# Algebra representing the group scheme $\mathbb Z/ n\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, hopf-algebras, affine-schemes, group-schemes

as title says, I can not figure out the hopf algebra structure to put on $k^n$ to make it represent the group scheme $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. With the usual example of group schemes like $G_a$ or $G_m$ it is easy, but I can not use the same reasoning in this case it seems.

Help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

So the scheme $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ over a field $k$ is $\text{Spec}(k^{\oplus n})$. I'm going to label the points by some basis, say $e_0,...,e_{n-1}$.

The Hopf-algebra structure is a map $k^{ n}\rightarrow k^{ n} \otimes k^{ n}$ and we need that the preimage of the ideal $(e_i\otimes e_j)$ is the ideal $(e_{{i+j} \pmod n})$.

So define it like that, send the basis vector $e_i$ to the sum of basis vectors $\sum_{j,k} e_j\otimes e_k$ whenever $j+k= i \pmod{n}$.

Example: Label the points of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ by $e_0,e_1$ corresponding to the prime ideals $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ in $k^2$. The Hopf algebra map is $k^2\rightarrow k^2\otimes k^2$ by $(0,1)\mapsto (1,0)\otimes (0,1) + (0,1) \otimes (1,0)$ and $(1,0)\mapsto (1,0) \otimes (1,0) + (0,1)\otimes (0,1)$. Now if I want to compute the product of two points like $e_0,e_1$ I need to look at the preimage of the ideal $(1,0)\otimes (0,1)$ under the Hopf algebra map. But this is just $(0,1)$ (which can be seen by observing the ideal generated by $(1,0)\otimes (0,1) + (0,1)\otimes (1,0)$ contains $(1,0)\otimes (0,1)((1,0)\otimes (0,1) + (0,1)\otimes (1,0))=(1,0)\otimes (0,1)$).

Constant group schemes aren't so fun to describe but you can generalize fairly easily to an arbitrary group in a way similar to the above.

For connected spectra $\text{Spec}(R)$ it's easy to see why the $R$-points $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}(R)$ are exactly $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If one is interested in more information, this is described in detail in Jantzen's book on algebraic groups.

Answer (score 1):

The $n$th roots of unity are well known to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. The algebra you're looking for should be $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^n-1)$

Comment: This doesn't represent the group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ over an arbitrary field $k$.

Comment: @reuns This still doesn't represent the group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ over an arbitrary field $k$...

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken. Should the coefficients be $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $k[y,x]/(\psi_n(y),x^n-1)$ (if $char(k) \nmid n$) with $\psi_n$ the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_n$

Comment: @Eoin It would be helpful if you gave us an explanation of why this answer is incorrect

Comment: @reuns What does killing $\psi_n$ add?

Comment: @leibnewtz The main problem is that when you start with an arbitrary field $k$ you don't have $n$th roots of unity. Reuns gets rid of this problem by describing exactly when the constant group scheme $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to the $k$-group scheme $\mu_n$. But you can define constant group schemes regardless of base so these aren't the most general way to do it.

Comment: @Eoin Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @leibnewtz Sorry for my earlier brevity

Comment: @leibnewtz: the name of the game here is to describe a Hopf algebra $H$ over $k$ with the property that if $A$ is a $k$-algebra with no nontrivial idempotents, then the group of algebra homomorphisms $\text{Hom}(H, A)$  (with group structure determined by the comultiplication of $H$) is always just the group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, with algebra homomorphisms $A \to B$ inducing the identity. The group algebra of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ does not solve this problem; instead the group we get is the group $\mu_n(A)$ of $n^{th}$ roots of unity. This group scheme is actually what is called the...

Comment: ...Cartier dual of the constant group scheme $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. In general, if $G$ is a finite group and we want to write down the corresponding finite group scheme, instead of taking the group algebra of $G$ we take what one might call the "group coalgebra" of $G$, namely $k^G$ with pointwise multiplication and comultiplication encoding the multiplication of $G$.